# Lipschitz constant for $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ from the definition of Lipschitz

Tags: derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Lipschitz constant for $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ from the definition of Lipschitz

Bit confused on how to do this from the definition instead of using any derivatives

So far I've reduced it to
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant |(x+y)(x-y)|$$ by simplification and noting that $f(x) \le 1$.

Comment: Do you need the best possible Lipschitz constant, or do you just need to find any Lipschitz constant that works?

Comment: Why is the denominator of that fraction not $(x^2 + y^2 + 1 + x^2.y^2)$

Comment: @jimmyk4542 any will do :)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\dfrac{|x-y||x+y|}{(1+|x|^{2})(1+|y|^{2})}\\
&\leq\dfrac{|x-y|(|x|+|y|)}{(1+|x|^{2})(1+|y|^{2})},
\end{align*}
now
\begin{align*}
|x|+|y|=(|x|,1)\cdot(1,|y|)\leq(1^{2}+|x|^{2})^{1/2}(1^{2}+|y|^{2})^{1/2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|x|+|y|}{(1+|x|^{2})(1+|y|^{2})}\leq\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|^{2})^{1/2}(1+|y|^{2})^{1/2}}<1.
\end{align*}

Comment: What does $|x| + |y| = (|x|,1) . (1,|y|)$ mean?

Comment: The inner product of the vectors $(|x|,1)$ and $(1,|y|)$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

$|f(x)-f(y)| =|\dfrac{y^2-x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}|$

$= \dfrac{|y-x||x+y|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}.$

Note: $|x+y| \le |x|+|y| \le$

$ \sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}\le$

$(1+ x^2) +(1+y^2).$

Hence:

$|f(x)-f(y)| \lt$

$ |x-y|( \dfrac{1}{1+y^2} +\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}) \le$

$2 |x-y|$.

Note :$ |x| =\sqrt{x^2} \lt \sqrt{x^2+1} \le x^2+1.$